# binarysearch c code error

Tags: c, binary

here is my binarysearch code. what i want to do is when i put something(which is not in list) showing 'the number is not in list'. but it didnt work well i dont know why

```
int compare(int, int);

int binsearch(int list[], int searchnum, int left, int right);

int main() {


    int right, left, middle;
    int list[MAX_NUM] = { 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};

    int searchnum,count=0;
    int answer;
    right = MAX_NUM-1;
    left = 0;
    printf("n : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &searchnum);

    answer=binsearch(list, searchnum, left, right);

    if (answer == -1)
        printf("%d is not in list", searchnum);
    else    
        printf("%d", answer);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int compare(int x, int y) {

    if (x< y) return -1;
    else if (x == y) return 0;
    else return 1;

}


int binsearch(int list[], int searchnum, int left, int right) {

    int middle;
    while (left <= right) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        switch (compare(list[middle], searchnum)) {
        case -1: left = middle - 1;
            break;
        case 0: return middle;
        case 1: right = middle - 1;

        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didnt work well"? Did you try to find out why or in which cases it fails?

Comment: `case -1: left = middle - 1;` --> `case -1: left = middle + 1;`

Comment: You need to lean how to debug such simple bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `case -1: left = middle - 1;` to `case -1: left = middle + 1;`. 
Like you did you'll never find a number which is bigger than the median.

Comment: Nice Catch!! Buddy.

Comment: You dont have to like my comment!!

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm will be like

```
 middle = ( left + right )/2
 if middle < searchnum 
     left = middle + 1
 else if middle > searchnum
     right = middle - 1
 else
     return 0
```

so it will search the greater half or lesser half recursively based on the condition since the array is sorted